# How to connect to Elementary using X2GO?

Tags: networking

I would like to use x2go to connect to my Elementary OS machine, but don't know what session type or custom session to use.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

As per x2go Client's "[Desktop Environment Compatibility](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:de-compat)" page, Elementary OS's "Pantheon" shell (of the Gnome Desktop Environment) is officially not supported.  You could open a new bug report with "wishlist" severity, following the instructions [here](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:bugs).  It won't be easy to support Pantheon, because there's already other rather difficult problems blocking x2go client's support of the newest Gnome versions.

Another option might be to install a second desktop environment (such as XFCE, or LXDE, which x2go client fully supports) on your Elementary OS box, alongside Pantheon.  But that would be a kludge, and I wouldn't be surprised if you encountered many problems and annoyances, because XFCE and LXDE wouldn't use Elementary's "switchboard" technology.  **Elementary OS strongly assumes you'll use Pantheon, and only Pantheon.**  You can't choose between DE's at the lightdm login screen, for instance.

If x2go is crucial for you right now, consider switching to a Linux distro such as LXLE, which uses LXDE from the get-go.  Just like Elementary, LXLE is designed to be very lightweight.

Comment: I guess the development for x2go has slow down a bit, since there is no word for support for Pantheon. even though it has been recognized in both the freedesktop.org menu specification and in AppStream for over a year now. You are right about the inconsistency. I tried x2go with openbox on elementary OS. The pantheon shell has a black window behind it and it does seem kludgy. I am torn.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, however, it might still pop up.  If you connect using "X2Go/X11 Desktop Sharing" it will render the 'Console" view or the same view that is seen when you log into the computer physically.

Session Type Settings:

[image: Session Type Settings screen shot]

For your viewing pleasure:

[image: Screenshot of the Running Desktop]